# How can I simultaneously complete two sets of tasks in python when one depends on the other?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a large number of small files to download and process from s3.

The downloading is fairly fast as the individual files are only a few megabytes each. Together, they are about 100gb. The processing takes roughly twice as long as the downloading takes and is purely cpu bound. Therefore, by completing the processing in multiple threads while downloading other files, it should be possible to shorten the overall runtime.

Currently, I am downloading a file, processing it and moving on the next file. Is there a way in python where I download all files one after another and process each one as soon as it completes downloading? The key difference here is that while each file is processing, the another is always downloading.

My code looks like:

```
files = {'txt': ['filepath1', 'filepath2', ...], 
         'tsv': ['filepath1', 'filepath2', ...]
        } 

for kind in files.keys():
    subprocess.check_call(f'mkdir -p {kind}', shell=True)
    subprocess.call(f'mkdir -p {kind}/normalized', shell=True)

    for i, file in enumerate(files[kind]):
        subprocess.call(f'aws s3 cp s3://mys3bucket.com/{file} {kind}/', shell=True)
        f = file.split('/')[-1]
        subprocess.check_call('my_process_function --input "{kind}/{f}" --output "{kind}/normalized/normalize_{f}" --units relab', shell=True)
```

I've also written a multiprocessing solution where I can simultaneously download and process multiple files, but this doesn't result in a speed improvement as the network speed was already saturated. The bottleneck is in the processing. I've included it in case it helps you guys.

```
from contextlib import closing
from os import cpu_count
from multiprocessing import Pool

def download_and_proc(file, kind='txt'):
    subprocess.call(f'aws s3 cp s3://mys3bucket.com/{file} {kind}/', shell=True)
    f = file.split('/')[-1]
    subprocess.check_call('my_process_function --input "{kind}/{f}" --output "{kind}/normalized/normalize_{f}" --units relab', shell=True)

with closing(Pool(processes=cpu_count()*2)) as pool:
        pool.map(download_and_proc, files)
```

Comment: What's the problem with your multiprocessing code?  Seems to have the right idea -- if the network is full then that's a bottleneck, but that doesn't prevent completed files from being processed, yes?

Comment: You are a bit unclear in your description; is the performance bound by the time to download the files or processing the files? And in either case, why does your `multiprocessing` solution not help? I don't understand from your description.

Comment: @Stabledog Thanks for the reply. I think the key is that the processing takes longer than the downloading. So while I can download multiple files simultaneously and that's good, I'm not utilizing my network constantly. It will download the files (saturate network speed), then process the files while not downloading anything. then repeat.

Comment: @JohanL I've added some details above that might help explain further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current multiprocessing code should be pretty close to optimal over the long term. It won't always be downloading at maximum speed, since the same threads of execution that are responsible for downloading a file will wait until the file has been processed before downloading another one. But it should usually have all the CPU consumed in processing, even if some network capacity is going unused. If you tried to always be downloading too, you'd eventually run out of files to download and the network would go idle for the same amount of time, just all at the end of the batch job.

One possible exception is if the time taken to process a file is always *exactly* the same. Then you might find your workers running in lockstep, where they all download at the same time, then all process at the same time, even though there are more workers than there are CPUs for them to run on. Unless the processing is somehow tied to a real time clock, that doesn't seem likely to occur for very long. Most of the time you'd have some processes finishing before others, and so the downloads would end up getting staggered.

So improving your code is not likely to give you much in the way of a speedup. If you think you need it though, you could split the downloading and processing into two separate pools. It might even work to do one of them as a single-process loop in the main process, but I'll show the full two-pool version here:

```
def download_worker(file, kind='txt'):
    subprocess.call(f'aws s3 cp s3://mys3bucket.com/{file} {kind}/', shell=True)
    return file

def processing_worker(file, kind='txt')
    f = file.split('/')[-1]
    subprocess.check_call('my_process_function --input "{kind}/{f}" --output "{kind}/normalized/normalize_{f}" --units relab', shell=True)

with Pool() as download_pool, Pool() as processing_pool:
    downloaded_iterator = download_pool.imap(download_worker, files)  # imap returns an iterator
    processing_pool.map(processing_worker, downloaded_iterator)
```

This should both download and process as fast as your system is capable. If the downloading of a file takes less time that its processing, then it's pretty likely that the first pool will be done before the second one, which the code will handle just fine. If the processing is not the bottleneck, it will support that too (the  second pool will be idle some of the time, waiting on files to finish downloading).